# Why do I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while reading .csv file?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons, opencsv

I'm trying to read .csv file like below:

```
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("przedmioty.csv"));

CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("Name", "Teacher", "Years").withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());

for (CSVRecord csvRecord: csvParser) {
    // Accessing Values by Column Index

    String name = csvRecord.get(0);
    //Accessing the values by column header name
    String Teacher= csvRecord.get(1);
    String years = csvRecord.get(2);

    //Printing the record
    System.out.println("Record Number - " + csvRecord.getRecordNumber());
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Teacher: " + Teacher);
    System.out.print("Years : " + years );
    System.out.println("\n\n");
}
```

That's how my .csv looks like

```
    Name            Teacher                 Years
    Math            Leszek Krauze           2
    X               Grimm Dostojowksi       3
    Y               Dimitriv Vladiskovic    4
```

I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord.get(CSVRecord.java:79)
at main.Task01.main(Task01.java:294)
```

I use apache commons csv.

Comment: Is that the literal character content of the .csv file? I don't see any commas in it, which makes me think it may be tab-separated rather than comma-separated.

Comment: @EvanVanderZee Yea it is tab-separated. I'm using excel so it's' how it is

Comment: Don't save as .txt in Excel, save as .csv.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with the following code and it is working fine for me. You can also check. I am using Common CSV version 1.4. Please check below the code. I have modified the code below.

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Reader in =
        new FileReader(
            "przedmioty.csv");
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records =
        CSVFormat.TDF
    .withRecordSeparator("\r\n")
            .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
            .withHeader("Name", "Teacher", "Years")
            .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
            .parse(in);

    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : records) {
      String name = csvRecord.get(1);
      // Accessing the values by column header name
      String Teacher = csvRecord.get(2);
      String years = csvRecord.get(3);

      // Printing the record
      System.out.println("Record Number -> " + csvRecord.getRecordNumber());
      System.out.println("Name: " + name);
      System.out.println("Teacher: " + Teacher);
      System.out.print("Years : " + years);
      System.out.println("\n\n");
    }
  }
}
```

There is some problem with your mentioned tab separated CSV file.
I provide below the github link so that you can run and test and it has also an csv file inside testdata folder. It is maven based project.

https://github.com/debjava/sample-tab-csv-parser
Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I have tested with comma separated file, if it does not work for a different csv, please let me know so that I can help you. Both of us will learn.

Comment: Actually i'm still gettin' Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord.get(CSVRecord.java:79)
 at main.Task01.main(Task01.java:301)

Comment: Did you check the code which I provided ? I tested with comma separated csv file ? Do you have a different type of csv file ?

Comment: For some reason my .csv is tab separated due to fact that i'm using excel.

Comment: You can try now, I have provided all the details.

Comment: Let me know whether it is working fine for you or not.